# Is there a way to re-run a Test in a pipeline until it passes before continuing running the next ones?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

So I'm using Azure Devops to run pipelines for my Selenium automated Tests. But lets say the first Test (TestA) is saving some preferences that will be needed for the rest of the tests (TestB, TestC)... Is there any way so that the pipeline will run all tests sequentially until each of them passes? So if TestA fails, rerun it X times, but if it never passes do not run the next Tests?
The only setting in Azure Devops I know that is related to that is Rerun Failed Tests, but it does not work for this case, as It will rerun failed tests after a first run for all of them

I have tried the [Retry] attribute but It didnt work

Comment: Is there any update about this ticket? Feel free to let me know if the answer can give you some help.

Comment: I created a request ticket on the Developer Community as you said. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way so that the pipeline will run all tests sequentially until each of them passes? So if TestA fails, rerun it X times, but if it never passes do not run the next Tests?

I am afraid that there is no methods in Azure DevOps can meet your requirement.

The current process supported by Azure DevOps is to run all tests first and then retry failed tests for X times.

I can fully understand your requirement. You can create a suggestion ticket in [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/AzureDevOps/suggest) to report your requirement.